# React onRouteChange

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I am trying to make my Header component render when the Route is changed.
I tried using onChange and onValueChange on the Switch but neither one gets called.
Is there a way to call a function whenever the route gets changed?

```
<Switch>
  <Route path="/posts/new" component={PostsNew}/>
  <Route path="/posts/:id" component={PostsShow}/>
  <Route exact path="/" component={PostsIndex}/>
</Switch>
```

Comment: Add handler to listen to router and then create the store to save last state and sent custom event when it happined

Comment: That might work in an older version of react router. I'm using 3.10.10

Answer (score 1):

After digging through the React Router docs (https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/withRouter) I found a solution.

To make my header component update when the route changes all I had to do was import withRouter:

```
import {withRouter} from 'react-router-dom';
```

and export the class using withRouter:

```
export default withRouter((connect(null, mapStateToProps)(Header)));
```